# How do I set a firewall rule to block communication between NICs on the same computer?

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I just added two NICs to my PC. They are connected to two separate networks. Is it possible to set the windows firewall to block communication between the two NICs? I'm on Windows 10 OS.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: By default, your PC won't act as a bridge/router/gateway between networks. That's something you have to enable if you want it to happen, like by enabling Internet Connection Sharing. Was that your concern? Or were you trying to prevent certain software on your own PC from accessing the "wrong" network?

Comment: Yes, that is my concern. So, does that mean that no firewall rules are necessary?

Comment: That's correct, if your computer is not configured to forward traffic from one network to another, it won't forward traffic from one network to another. You don't need a firewall rule to block a behavior that your computer wasn't going to do anyway.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. How can set the default DNS server for nslookup? It automatically uses the one I don't want. How can I change the default server?

Comment: The way this site works best is when there's only one question per Question post. So you should really edit this Question post to remove the DNS question, and then post the DNS question as a separate Question post.

Comment: I have removed my second question and asked it in a different thread. Thank you for your help.